# SQLalchemy python3 s = select([users]) Namerror: name 'users' is not defined

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Here is the code:

```
#from hooks.basic import *
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.engine import *
from sqlalchemy.sql import *
import os

db_list = []
word_list=[]

#if os.path.exists("logs.db"):
   # pass

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///logs.db', echo=False)

connection = engine.connect()

try:
    connection.execute(
    """
    CREATE TABLE users (
        sentence VARCHAR
    );
    """
    )
except:
    pass




def hook_db(text = None):

    """Used to save what was said"""

    global db_list
    #global word_list


    db_list.append(text)

    connection.execute(
    """
    INSERT INTO users (sentence) VALUES (?);
    """,
    text
    )
    return db_list

def insert_db(text):

    connection.execute(
  """                                                                                                  
    INSERT INTO users (sentence) VALUES                                                 (?);                                                             
    """,
    text
    )

def output_db():

    s = select([users])
    result = conn.execute(s) 
    return(result)

def input_(input__: dict):
    global word_list
    word_list = input__
    return word_list
```

I know the code doesn't make a lot of sense, but does somebody know why I get the following error?

```
  File "/home/tsumugi/python/git_python/kontainer/kontena/utils/dbutils.py", line 60,  in output_db
    s = select([users])
NameError: name 'users' is not defined
```

I read the following tutorial http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/tutorial.html, under the section "selecting" it told me to do it like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [define the `users` `Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/tutorial.html#define-and-create-tables) first:

```
users = Table('user', metadata, Column('sentence', String()))
```

Complete example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, String, MetaData, select

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
metadata = MetaData(engine)

users = Table('user', metadata, Column('sentence', String()))
metadata.create_all(engine)

connection = engine.connect()

s = select([users])
result = connection.execute(s)
```

Comment: I think this worked (at least I'm not getting any errors anymore)